# Python Elasticsearch create index mapping

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to create a ES index with custom mapping with elasticsearch python to increase the size of text in each document:

```
mapping = {"mapping":{
           "properties":{
             "Apple":{"type":"text","ignore_above":1000},
             "Mango":{"type":"text","ignore_above":1000}
           }
          }}
```

Creation:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es1 = Elasticsearch([{"host":"localhost","port":9200}])
es1.indices.create(index="hello",body=mapping)
```

Error:

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Mapping definition for [Apple] has unsupported parameters: [ignore_above : 10000]')
```

But I checked the elasticsearch website on how to increase the text length limit and `ignore_above` was the option given there.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html

Any suggestions on how to rectify this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ignore_above` setting is only for `keyword` types not `text`, so just change your mapping to this and it will work:

```
mapping = {"mapping":{
       "properties":{
         "Apple":{"type":"text"},
         "Mango":{"type":"text"}
       }
      }}
```

If you absolutely need to be able to specify `ignore_above` then you need to change the type to `keyword`, like this:

```
mapping = {"mapping":{
       "properties":{
         "Apple":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":1000},
         "Mango":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":1000}
       }
      }}
```

Comment: But I need to change the ```ignore_above``` to 1000 since I am trying to load a pandas DF which has string values greater than 256, the default length.